# Do you know any tools to make such graphs?

Tags: latex

Do you know tools to make graphs like in the picture?

[image: picture]

Comment: Tikzpicture? See examples: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/nodes-and-shapes/

Answer (score -1):

You can try [mathcha.io](https://www.mathcha.io/editor) which is an online tool for creating tikz pictures used in tex documents.

Answer (score -1):

The package [tikz](http://www.texample.net/tikz/) is exactly what you need for that kind of plots.

Comment: You can find some useful examples [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/node-positioning/).